# Github integration with Gitlab - Token from organization

Tags: github, continuous-integration, gitlab, token

I have a Gitlab and Github account. What I want to do is to integrate Github with Gitlab. In order to do this a Github token should be generated and used by Gitlab, that is exactly what I have done.

But, when using this token, I only get the repositories from my own Github account. The repositories from the organization (where I'm the owner of) doesn't show up. How can I fix this?

Comment: HI Yil,
I don't think it's possible because you can have common Oauth authentication between Github and Gitlab. These applications won't share the tokens. So your Github token will only work for Github.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you didn't add the correct scopes when you created the GitHub personal access token. I just tested it again myself, and you need to select at least one key scope to get org details, and you likely want to add all scopes under `repo`, but decide that for your needs.

The scope you need to have so Gitlab can see your Org repos is called `read:org` under the `admin:org` header. All you need is read for Gitlab to be able to run CI pipelines on a mirrored github repo.

Here's a video from Gitlab that shows how to set it up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgl3F2j-1cI

Create a new Personal Access Token on GitHub [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new).